# Having trouble using Bean method in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a Java class and a Camel-route configured with XML and am trying to call the `getData` method from the Camel-route, but the method is not being invoked.

**Java class:**

```
class Test {
    public String getData(String name) {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Camel-route:**

```
<route id="validate" autoStartup="true" streamCache="true">
  <setHeader name="data">
    <simple>
      <method ref="test" method="getData('Test')"/>
    </simple>
  </setHeader>
</route>
```

In my camel-context.xml I've created the bean-reference as such:

```
<bean id="test" class="com.Test" />
```

Comment: The `ref` has to point to your class. Please show us the rest of your XML

Comment: @ErikKarlstrand this is the only camel route we written nothing else.. let us know if anything is missing. In camel-context.xml we have provided  bean id mapped to our class   <bean id="test" class="com.Test" />

Comment: Have you asserted that the route has actually started?

Comment: yes i tried to put <log message="test java call..........."/> statement.. & I can see the logger inside route

Comment: It's been a while since I developed anything in camel, but it looks like you're calling the method incorrectly. The parameter of the method should be the payload of your route and the method should only be referenced by name: `<method ref="test" method="getData" />`

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved now.. instead of using **method** tag use **bean** tag

```
<bean ref="test" method="getData" />
```